# JAX-RS expose OneToMany entities in GET

Tags: java, rest, jpa, jax-ws, jax-rs

I'm diving into Java EE, learning JPA and JAX-RS. 
I want to expose all OneToMany entities when a GET request is done on the "owned" side of the relation.

I created the entities Company and CompanyAddress, the company can have multiple addresses (OneToMany) and is mapped by the field companyId in the CompanyAddress entity.

I want to expose my company including all addresses when a GET is done on the company, other way around i only want the companyaddress to show when a GET is done on this field. How can I make this work?

in my Facade Class for Company:

```
@GET
@Path("{id}")
@Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
public Company find(@PathParam("id") Integer id) {
    return super.find(id);
}
```

In my entity class for Company:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "companyId",fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection<CompanyAddress> companyAddressCollection;
```

and

```
@XmlTransient
public Collection<CompanyAddress> getCompanyAddressCollection() {
    return companyAddressCollection;
}
```

And in my entity class for CompanyAddress

```
@JoinColumn(name = "companyId", referencedColumnName = "id")
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
private Company companyId;
```

Comment: What are your results when accessing the `GET` path?

Comment: Won't the XmlTransient discard the address from the XML, the exact opposite of what you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@XmlTransient` annotation is useful for resolving name collisions between a JavaBean property name and a field name or *preventing the mapping of a field/property*.

Remove the `@XmlTransient` annotation and the companyAddressCollection will be represented within the `XML` doc.

Comment: This worked for me, I moved the XMLTransient tag to the CompanyAddress entity! I am going to take a deeper look into all the annotations and their functionality.